# Rollover in Form

Tags: html, css, paypal

I have a navigation bar on our pending site made up of styled hyperlinks.

One of these hrefs was originally a PayPal link, but because of security concerns I have had to make this PP link an encrypted button instead.

The problem is that the hover image-swap effect that I apply to the links isn't applicable to the form image. I've tried every which-way (this.src to that.src, hover based on shifting background position) to implement this, but the complexity of forms vs the simplicity of href is proving problematical.

Given my code below, can anyone show me a non-Javascript way to either shift position of 'pp3.gif' or swap two other images to mimic the css hover image-swap I already have for the other list elements

```
    <li><a href="info.htm" target="iframe1">Information</a></li>
    <li>
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
           <input type="image" src="../buttons/pp3.gif" name="submit">
           <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7 ... END PKCS7-----">
       </form>
    </li>
    <li><a href="delivery.htm" target="iframe1">Livraison</a></li>
```

Thankee!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not using `<input type="image">`. It's quite inflexible compared to styling the input directly with CSS. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6S8Hs/

```
<ul>
<li><a href="info.htm" target="iframe1">Information</a></li>

<li>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
        <input class="hover-effect" type="submit" name="submit"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7 ... END PKCS7-----"/>
    </form>
</li>
<li><a href="delivery.htm" target="iframe1">Livraison</a></li></ul>
```

`ul{ list-style-type: none; }`

`ul li{ 
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}`

`.hover-effect{
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image:url("http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/t/o/toaster-kitten.jpg");
    display:block;
    border:none;
    color:transparent;
}`

`.hover-effect:hover{
   background-image:url("http://img.ehowcdn.com/other-people/ehow/images/a06/27/bh/care-newborn-kitten-mother-800x800.jpg"); 
}`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. My css text was very similar but your guidance regarding dropping <input type="image"> and replacing this with a Class removed the confusion. Adding style= "cursor:pointer" to the Input tag turned my arrow pointer into the hand pointer, making my secure PayPal button appear like all the other hyperlinks in the navbar -- many thanks. I'm not clear about the 'typo' referred to in the list code however, or the reference to closing the input tag. What exactly is missing or awry here?

Comment: Your question was edited by another user, but previously the closing tag for the `<li>` was spelled `<il>`. The comment about the input tags was actually not true, sorry. I removed it. With HTML5 they don't need to be closed. So you can ignore that :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the code typo also -- fixed!